# search filter for object array having heterogeneous type. is throwing error in angular 9

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

i want to search a array of object with key,value pair. But it's throwing error in console as shown:
**core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function**

```
a = [
{
  id: 0,
  name: "xyz",
  grade: "x",
  frade: [
    { name: "Paul", country: "Canada" },
    { name: "Lea", country: "Italy" },
    { name: "John", country: "Italy" }
  ]
},
{
  id: 1,
  name: "yaya",
  grade: "x"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "x",
  frade: "d"
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "a",
  grade: "b"
}];

filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
return arr.filter(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
  });
});
}
searchCharacter(res: any) {  // is keyup event in html
  console.log(this.filterIt(this.a, 'b'));
}
```

Comment: How is `filterIt` getting called?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert object[key] in string:

```
String(obj[key]).includes
```